# AS3 : How to activate android air app?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I created an alarm app for android by adobe air in flash cs6.It works correctly and alarms at correct time and show a message on screen . I want write "something in as3 code" that when my app is in the background change to foreground and user can see the message. What is that code? I did some search over the internet and found something about .ANE files , is it possible to do my project with this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Background Service but it's not possible to do it in AIR/AS3 on Android, it must be done in Java.

The Service will wake up the application when it's time.
You can write an ANE to do this: [here](http://www.lorenzonuvoletta.com/create-an-air-ane-for-android-to-dispatch-background-tasks/).

Comment: thanks for your answer , but it was too Complicated for me :( Isn't a simple way to do that !?

Comment: No, actionscript/air/flash is not designed to be used a background process, the only way to use it as such is by writing ANE's to hook into

Comment: @SharpEdge in my case I programmed a Pedometer which works fine if the app is in the foreground but if I lock the Screen the Pedometer does not Count anymore, so you say that there is no way to solve something like this?

Comment: I say that after 4 years air technology is dead and you should use something else

Comment: @SharpEdge it is an old Project which was programmed using air that is why I was asking. We do not program in air anymore .)